# SMTP connect() failed PHPMailer Using MailGun

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, mailgun

I was trying to connect my MailGun SMTP details with PHP Mailer and it doesn't work at all it throws error like below

```
2020-10-16 09:58:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server2.dnsboost.com ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Fri, 16 Oct 2020 15:28:34 +0530 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2020-10-16 09:58:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO website.com
2020-10-16 09:58:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server2.dnsboost.com Hello website.com [192.154.231.187]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2020-10-16 09:58:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-10-16 09:58:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-10-16 09:58:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-10-16 09:58:34
2020-10-16 09:58:34
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
failed
```

I've tried all the suggested methods to fix this but none worked!

I tested the credentials with SMTP tester sites and they work just perfectly fine and send test message to my inbox but it doesn't work when I try to use it with PHPMailer...

Answer (score 0):

This exact error is [described in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure) that's linked from the error message!

> In an SMTP transcript this will typically be shown as trying to send a STARTTLS command immediately followed by a QUIT command.

It's nothing to do with credentials, everything to do with the TLS configuration on your server. Try setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`, and you'll then need to check your CA certificate bundle, as described in the guide.